# I am a little confused about this sentence

Tags: meaning

I am a little confused when I saw this sentence emailed from a customer.

He said:

> We want tobeco mini 25mm new one in many colors.

P.S. "Tobeco mini 25mm" is a product name.

What is meaning of this sentence?

1. They wanted the product which is new version in many colors for choosing, not old version.
2. They wanted this product and will order many colors of it(Not mentioned the quantity) .
3. They wanted the one for each color(If there are 2 colors, they want 2. 1 red and 1 pink).

Which one should be correct? If this sentence grammatical and if he omitted some words?

Comment: Could you provide more context to the sentence?  I am inclined to believe they want one, the new one that comes in many colours, as opposed to the old one that didn't.  Perhaps they don't care which colour - is this product something that matters if it is in different colours e.g. ink colour matters but a toaster does not etc.

Comment: Don't guess. Reply to him something like this, "Thank you for the inquiry. How many units of "Tobeco Mini 25mm" would you like to purchase? Is it okay with you if we select the colors randomly when you place an order?" and don't forget to mention where they can get more specific information or the available units/models/etc. on your website or in your catalog. It'd be much more effective this way. Best of luck.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As written, the sentence is not grammatical and hard to understand.  All of the possible understandings you have listed seem equally reasonable to me as a native speaker.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think you can know the exact meaning without additional information.

This is because "new one" (singular) conflicts with "in many colors" (plural).
Since in some languages there is no written distinction between singular and plural noun forms, the writer could have meant either one or several.

Answer (score 0):

As written, this sounds like an order for

> We want tobeco mini 25mm new one in many colours.
>   *one, new tobeco mini 25mm in multiple colours*

The "one" is for a single tobeco tank.

The colour would either be Zombie White, or Zombie Green (all other colours are solid) and the glass enclosure also comes in several different colours.

[image: here]